# C# Data Exported to csv is Being Displayed as Text in the Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I've got an issue with a simple web application I'm developing in C# using VS 2013.  It's supposed to take some values from a grid view and export them to a .csv file, however when I test, it's just taking that information and displaying it as text on the page.  I wrote a test page with a single link button and tried to export a values to a text file but I get the same result.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = "1,1,1,,,";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(test);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachement; test.txt");
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

[Here's the output I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPvxj.png)

The code looks correct (I've compared it to several examples) but I still don't know why I'm not being prompted to save or open the file.  I've tried it in multiple browsers but I get the same result in each one.  Aside of adding line number Visual Studio is setup with default options.  Could there be a problem with VS? Or IIS? Or even my workstation?

Comment: And you seems to save it as txt not csv if Im not missing anything

Comment: `ContentType` is probably better off as `text/csv` as well

Comment: Try renaming file extension to .csv

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it was the:
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Dispostion","attachment; filename=test.txt")

That corrected the problem in test page so that it was prompting to save the text file.  Then I changed the Content Type to text/csv and tried again and again it prompted to save a csv file.  So I copied that code an used it the page that was giving me the problem to begin with an that too is prompting to a csv file.  Thanks for all the input everyone.